# What is faster? SQL query with wildcards and ORs, or catch-all query with php loop for filtering?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, wildcard

I'm running a query on a single table. I need the end result to be an array of rows where the current user is listed as a participant in the message that the DB row records. The two participants columns are `staff` and `clients`, and the contain serialized arrays of user IDs and/or role name (e.g., `a:3:{i:0;s:8:"staffman";i:1;s:3:"203";i:2;s:3:"170";}`).

Would it be faster to try to filter out any non-matches for the current user all in the SQL query, or to do a catch-all query (maybe on several hundred rows), then loop through them to filter out the ones where the user is not a participant?

SQL option:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".self::$messages;
if($is_client) $query .= " WHERE type = 'clients'";
elseif($is_staff) $query .= " WHERE type = 'staff' AND (staff LIKE '%\"".$user->ID."\"%' OR staff LIKE 'staff\"%')";
elseif(!$is_admin)
{
    $query .= " WHERE type = 'staff' AND (staff LIKE '%\"".$user->ID."\"%' OR staff LIKE 'staff\"%' OR staff LIKE 'clientman%'";
    if($is_staffman) $query .= " OR staff LIKE 'staffman%'";
    if($is_accountant) $query .= " OR staff like 'accountant%'";
    $query .= ")";
}
$query .= " ORDER BY updated DESC";
```

LOOP Option:

```
$col = $is_client ? 'clients' : 'staff';
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".self::$messages." WHERE type = {$col} ORDER BY updated DESC";
// do the query, then check if there are results. if results...     
foreach($results as $msg)
{
    if(empty($msg->$col)) continue;
    $users = unserialize($msg->$col);
    if($is_client)
    {
        if(!in_array($user->ID, $users) && !in_array('client', $users)) continue;   
    }
    elseif(!$is_admin && $msg->created_by != $user->ID)
    {
        if(!in_array($user->ID, $users))
        {
            if(!in_array('staff', $users))
            {
                if(!$is_clientman || !in_array('clientman', $users))
                {
                    if(!$is_staffman || !in_array('staffman', $users))
                    {
                        if(!$is_accountant || !in_array('accountant', $users)) continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // match found, do stuff with it here
}
```

Comment: It's hard to predict performance of complex operations like this. Try it both ways and benchmark it.

Comment: Benchmark your alternatives. The database is made to handle stuff like this quick, and php is quite slow, so with just a guess, the query option will most likely be the quicker one. But a benchmark is always a good thing to do.

Comment: Sql will still be faster, even if it is doing scans. However, if you are able to normalize the JSON object into relationships with columns, then the performance will be immensely improved if you avoid the `LIKE` comparisons. If you continue to store JSON, you might look at MongoDB for this data - it will be able to index the payload.

Comment: Stuart, so normalizing then would involve, you're suggesting, creating a row in a different table for each element of the participants (staff, clients) array, referencing the message id in each row, one row per user? Is that what you're talking about? So that would be faster than doing LIKEs on single rows, right?

Comment: Which is faster when you test it?

Comment: Toby, I haven't benchmarked it yet. I need to create a bunch of rows to be able to do that. I'm just in the planning phase and thought there might be a general-wisdom answer to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always use SQL option in such case.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".self::$messages;
if($is_client) $query .= " WHERE type = 'clients'";
elseif($is_staff) $query .= " WHERE type = 'staff' AND (staff LIKE '%\"".$user->ID."\"%' OR staff LIKE 'staff\"%')";
elseif(!$is_admin)
{
    $query .= " WHERE type = 'staff' AND (staff LIKE '%\"".$user->ID."\"%' OR staff LIKE 'staff\"%' OR staff LIKE 'clientman%'";
    if($is_staffman) $query .= " OR staff LIKE 'staffman%'";
    if($is_accountant) $query .= " OR staff like 'accountant%'";
    $query .= ")";
}
$query .= " ORDER BY updated DESC";
```

**Why ?**

1.See you already get less records(those are Needed only) by filtering thru WHERE clause.There is no point in fetching all the records and filtering it in php.

2.See its headache to manage code in PHP as it got complicated.

3.Less no.of lines.

4.It is managed by SQL most of the time, php logic will make it slow.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted the answer above because it was a clear and definitive answer to the question I posed. However, Stuart (in the comments) suggested I try to normalize my structure rather than scan serialized arrays with LIKES and the like. So that's what I've done.

Instead of saving my participants array in serialized form in the same table as the `messages` table, I created a new table called `message_recipients` with just three columns `(id,mid,user)`, where `mid` refers to the `id` column from the `messages` table, and where `user` stores the individual user id or role name.

So the trickiest part (which wasn't really that tricky) was how to manage adding and deleting rows from the `message_recipients` table when the user changes the allowed recipients for a given message. (In the form, they have two multiselect dropdowns—one for staff, one for clients).

So here's how I managed the updated/changing participants part:

For each field (staff and clients), I pass my function two arrays, one with the new participants and one with the old participants. (If the message is being created, then the old participants array is simply empty.)

Then here's the function (basically just four lines of actual work):

```
public function update_participants($mid = false, $new_staff = array(), $old_staff = array(), $new_clients = array(), $old_clients = array())
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(empty($mid)) return array();
    $add = array_filter(array_unique(array_merge(array_diff($new_staff, $old_staff), array_diff($new_clients, $old_clients))));
    $delete = array_filter(array_unique(array_merge(array_diff($old_staff, $new_staff), array_diff($old_clients, $new_clients))));
    if(!empty($add)) $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".self::$participants." (mid,user) VALUES(".$mid.",\"".implode("\"),(".$mid.",\"", $add)."\")");
    if(!empty($delete)) $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".self::$participants." WHERE mid = {$mid} AND user IN (\"".implode("\", \"", $delete)."\")");
    return array('added'=>$add, 'deleted'=>$delete);
}
```

Then I return the resulting arrays of people being added or deleted, so I can play with that in my email notifications stuff.

Then, now that we're normalized, the original problem of querying the table to get all the messages in which the current user is a participant is much faster and simpler:

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM '.self::$messages.' a, '.self::$participants.' b';
if(!$is_admin) 
{
    $query .= ' WHERE (b.user = '.$user->ID;
    if($is_client) $query .= ' OR b.user = "client"';
    elseif($is_staff) $query .= ' OR b.user = "staff"';
    else
    {
        if($is_clientman) $query .= ' OR b.user = "clientman"';
        if($is_staffman) $query .= ' OR b.user = "staffman"';
        if($is_accountant) $query .= ' OR b.user = "accountant"';
        $query .= ' OR a.created_by = '.$user->ID;
    }
    $query .= ') AND b.mid = a.id';
}
$query .= ' ORDER BY a.updated DESC';
```

Admins get everything, and everyone else only get any messages where their user id or their user role is found in the participants table. (Some roles have multiple roles, hence the triple `if` statements, rather than `elseifs`.

I've tested it with every possible configuration with different users. Works like a charm.

And no LIKEs, no wildcards, and no PHP loops.

Thanks everyone for the help.